# Atomic superhero cartoon pilot from early 1990s

Tags: cartoon, episode-identification, super-hero

This has been driving me crazy all day, yet I am embarrassed to ask it.

I am trying to remember the name of a kids’ animated cartoon I watched obsessively, produced around 1992+-2 years, for the US market.  I believe my copy of it came on a promotional VHS from Burger King.

It involved a group of superheroes who gained their powers from some sort of atomic science project.  I believe “city” was in the name - “heroes of mega city”, or “atomic city heroes”. Something like that.

One of the main male heroes was a cyborg who rode around on a buzzsaw-like wheel instead of legs, I think.  He may have been blue or silver.

I believe this was a pilot episode of a series, as I never saw another episode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I knew this would happen - posting the question jogged my memory almost immediately.  The cartoon is 1992’s “Defenders of Dynatron City”.

The cyborg mentioned above is actually a misremembered version of the character Buzzsaw Girl - a humanoid who moves around on a buzzsaw-like monowheel lower body.

Comment: Hi Adam...you can mark you own self answered question as correct, please.